# WordPress Child Theme - Modify a file within folders

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am in the process of creating a child theme for a WordPress theme. One of the files I need to make modifications to is... includes/functions/recent_sidebars.php.

Am I able to create this file within my child theme as I would a page template file and it would load this file instead of the parent theme's unmodified version?

If so, it is not working for me. I even tried putting it in the same folder hierarchy and no go.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Regards,

John

Comment: What is the parent theme?

Comment: Also, check that the permissions are set correctly.